# Autowiring Controller doesn't work after adding entityManagerFactory bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, neo4j, cassandra, kundera

I've wrote a spring mvc webserver which uses NEO4j as data backend. Now i want to expand this with cassandra, so the server should be able to use both databases.

I have followed these 2 tutorials on how to combine Kundera (A JPA based Cassandra API):
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Using-Kundera-with-Spring
https://code.google.com/p/kundera/wiki/HowToUseKunderaWithSpring

But i'm not able to add the entitymanagerfactory bean to my applicationcontext.xml file.

```
     <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="cassandra_pu"/>
    </bean>
```

When i do this, spring gives an error that it can not create any of the already existing controllers that my webserver uses.

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'indexController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private bmsapp.service.DataBasePopulator bmsapp.controller.IndexController.dbPopulator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] for bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private bmsapp.service.DataBasePopulator bmsapp.controller.IndexController.dbPopulator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] for bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 22 more
```

Those controllers are created by using the @Controller annotation in their class files and by autowiring them in the files where they are used. This works fine normally but when i add the entityManagerFactory bean it suddenly stops working. How is this possible?

My applicationContext file currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
">

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered 
    as Spring beans. For example @Controller and @Service. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="bmsapp" />

<!-- Activate Spring Data Neo4j repository support -->
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="data/graph.db" base-package="bmsapp.domain" />
<neo4j:repositories base-package="bmsapp.repository" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>

 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="cassandra_pu"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" />
<!-- context:annotation-config / -->
<!-- use this for Spring Jackson JSON support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

And my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="cassandra_pu">
    <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>     
    <properties>            
        <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="kundera.port" value="9160"/>
        <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="KunderaExamples"/>
        <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra"/>
        <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.pelops.PelopsClientFactory" />
        <property name="kundera.cache.provider.class" value="com.impetus.kundera.cache.ehcache.EhCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="kundera.cache.config.resource" value="/ehcache-test.xml"/>                  
    </properties>       
</persistence-unit>
```

SimpleComment domain class:

```
package bmsapp.domain;
 import javax.persistence.Column;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.Table;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "SIMPLE_COMMENT", schema = "KunderaExamples@cassandra_pu")
 @XmlRootElement(name = "SimpleComment")
 public class SimpleComment {
@Id
@Column(name = "COMMENT_ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "USER_NAME")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "COMMENT_TEXT")
private String commentText;

public SimpleComment() {
}

public SimpleComment(int commentId, String userName, String commentText) {
    this.id = commentId;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.commentText = commentText;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getCommentText() {
    return commentText;
}

public void setCommentText(String commentText) {
    this.commentText = commentText;
}
}
```

SpringExampleDao:

```
package bmsapp.repository;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import bmsapp.domain.SimpleComment;

@Service
public class SpringExampleDao
{
    @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private  EntityManager entityManager;

    public SimpleComment addComment(int id, String userName, String commentText)
    {
        SimpleComment simpleComment = new SimpleComment(id, userName, commentText);        
        entityManager.persist(simpleComment);
        return simpleComment;
    }

    public SimpleComment getCommentById(String Id)
    {

        SimpleComment simpleComment = entityManager.find(SimpleComment.class, Id);
        return simpleComment;
    }

    public List<SimpleComment> getAllComments()
    {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c from SimpleComment c");
        List<SimpleComment> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of dependencies for Spring are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the stacktrace is:

```
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
```

So you need to add a dependency to `spring-orm`, see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm.

However, I'm not sure that really solves your problem. In the description you're mentioning Neo4j and I cannot see what part of your description relates to that.

Comment: Thanks that did it! Turned out i was missing some more dependencies, i should pay more attention to the stacktraces next time :) Seems like those dependencies are required to get Kundera running with spring since i also tried it without spring and it worked fine. The missing class that you found has nothing to do with NEO4J but is required by the "entityManagerFactory" bean that i've added to the application context.